# Crontab errors while running python program

Tags: python, cron

I wrote a python program that checks a website for new posts, saves a log to a text file and sends me a text message if there is one. I am trying to run this every 5 minutes in a crontab. I am running it in a python environment. The cron file I used:

```
{*/5 * * * * /Users/my/opt/anaconda3/envs/webscrape/bin/python /Users/my/Desktop/Programming/preply_scrape.py > /dev/null 2>&1}
```

When I try and save this file in the cron editor I get this dialog box:

"“Terminal” would like to administer your computer. Administration can include modifying passwords, networking, and system settings"

and this error:

""/tmp/crontab.FATUtXZE46":0: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install"

I've been messing with crontab for a few day and even tried launchd but can't figure it out. Could this have something to do with file permissions? Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try putting your password when asked ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It never asks for a password just to allow. I just tired running sudo contrab -e and I get the same dialog box but no error this time. I don't get a text message as expected if the program was ran.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it my issue. The issue was that I had to give full disk access to the folder my python programmed was stored and cron. On Mac go to system preference -> Security & Privacy -> Full disk access (on the left side panel). Click on the lock and enter your password to make changes. Click on the plus sign, browse to application -> utilities and find cron. Do the same for your file path.